# How to get data from sqlite to a listview in android without a Datahandler class

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, listview, datahandler

I want to get data from Sqlite to a `listview` without a `Datahandler` class

I have add data into Sqlite without Datahandler* class

My database name is Mydb,and table name is mytable it has two columns name and phone.

Comment: what u mean datahandler here?

Comment: a separete class which has sqlite fuction to create table and other stuffs.

Comment: i have insert data through actvity.and i want get those data through another activity

Comment: so get the data through the select query if you have inserted into the database

Comment: can you please explain more sir

Comment: Simply use `rawQuery()` for the **queries** statements and `execSQL()` for the **commands**.